# How to create a mesh from a set of 3d vectors and then find its edges?

Tags: vector, mesh, edge-detection, creation

I have a set of 3d vectors and I would like to transform it into a mesh, and then find out which vectors are connected to which vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delaunay Triangulation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation